# How to generate sample problems

Tags: soft-question

How do professors and authors generate problems for their exams and textbooks? To what extent are problems inspired by problems from existing texts? And how does someone who understands the material thoroughly gauge the difficulty of the questions he or she is creating?

Comment: This looks like a better fit for http://matheducators.stackexchange.com

Comment: To those voting to close: this certainly does **not** belong on meta.MSE.

Comment: I hope for a clearer realization of the mathematical issues involved in making useful problems. A huge percentage of student contact/ learning/ understanding/ motivation is wrapped up in problems. Dismissing them is irrelevant to 'mathematics' within someone's idea of 'scope' seems unhelpful. I do not believe for a moment that my Answ exhausts the informative possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

As an occasional textbook author and frequent reviewer of texts
for several publishers, I have thought quite a bit about the issues you raise.

First, it is obviously true that really good questions migrate
freely among textbooks, usually with minor changes or embellishments.
In some cases it is pretty clear that a question is original
in a particular book, and in that case I think authors who
take a question or an idea for a question for their own book
ought to give credit to the original source more often than
seems to happen in practice. But many interesting questions
have become so 'standard' that there is probably no telling where
they originated.

Also, I have always tried to invent new questions or to think of new
uses for classic ones. But this gets to your second good question
about judging difficulty. I know of no way to be sure about
the difficulty of a question for students than to test it out
in several classes. If the question is really original, there seems no end to the surprises how students
will interpret the wording or the approach they will take to
solving it. Often a question can go from frustrating and time wasting
to really useful by introducing it in a new way, putting it in
a slightly different context, or wording it more carefully.

Sometimes, a horribly confusing question persists unchanged through multiple
editions of essentially the same textbook. I know of one quirky question in a much-used, multi-author probability book
that has alternated correct and
incorrect answers in the back of the book through five editions. (First thing I do when a new edition comes out is to check what
answer they're giving $this$ time.)
It's not a really a deep or difficult question, just badly worded.
One wonders what flaws in lines of communication can allow such
things to happen.

Recently, one of the difficulties with some commercial Internet courses and hastily
published on-line books is that the quality and variety of questions
seems to suffer during whatever process of authoring and reviewing
is being used. My personal view is that computer-generated questions
in online support services for some textbooks can be especially
problematic. In randomly changing numbers in some types of
problems, the problems can become nonsensical in unexpected
ways. Also, the answer-recognition software is sometimes not
clever enough to recognize an essentially correct answer in an
unanticipated format.

Overall, many questions assigned are engaging and useful. Even more so because many 
instructors work hard to assign the best questions available.
However, students who encounter difficulty with a question
should always keep in mind the possibility that the deficiency
may be in the question (or the answer provided). Don't spend
an inordinate amount of time on any one 'impossible' question without
checking somehow where the real difficulty lies.